# Бутыль или банка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Трехлитровые и больше банки часто называть "бутыль" (причем, в народе — еще и "бУтыль"). Но, как мне кажется, "бутыль" — это узкий и высокий сосуд, но никак не банка. 
Правильно ли называть большие банки бутылями?

Comment: И ещё спрошу про *бутыль*. Какого рода это слово?

*Трёхлитровый бутыль* или *трёхлитровая бутыль*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Бутыль, как и бутылка, женского рода. Согласно толковому словарю,  это большая бутылка или  банка округлой формы с узким горлом. 
Так что если у вас обычную трехлитровую банку называют бутыль, это не правильно. У нас бутылью называют очень большую банку, действительно у нее узкое горло. В таких обычно вино ставят. Сколько литров в ней,  не знаю, но никак не меньше десяти.

Answer (score 3):

Бутыль по изначальному смыслу - "бочонок", как утверждают справочники. Цилиндрическое вместилище из стекла с горлышком, которое затыкается **пробкой**, по примеру настоящей деревянной бочки. Если с пробкой - бутыль, а если с широкой накидной крышкой посудина - то банка! Вот такое отличие. Сколько внутрь влезает литров под пробки - на этом основана разница между бутылкой и бутылью. Знаменитая русская **четверть** (ведра) вмещала три с небольшим литра. Это явно бутыль.

[image: Четверть]

Что еще? В бутыли обычно наливают жидкости, в банки закладывают варенья и соленья. Кстати, это очень удобно : наливать из бутылей самогоночку и доставать из банок огурчики с грибочками. Наоборот было бы проблематично : спиртное быстро кончится, а закуску так не достанут...

Answer (score 1):

Да, бутыль (она) в отношении стеклянного сосуда большой емкости - литров эдак от трех - вполне уместно.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, 3л банка называется четверть, от старорусской меры "ведро, 12л